# How to Address the following error when importing CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda yesterday and went to begin a project this afternoon. When importing my data I did the below, as per ususal:

```
import pandas as pd
covid = pd.read_csv("covidbb")
```

I was met with an error stating : `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'covidbb'`

I really am not sure how to go about this, I watched a few YT vids to set a WD and other threads but just do not understand what is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: error means it's not able to find the file. try providing absolute path it will work

Comment: Your file has no extension? `.csv`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need right click your .py file and press set console as working directory with caring your .py and csv in the same directory.
If it is not helpful you can change your script as:

> covid = pd.read_csv("covidbb",'r')

Comment: when I popped that code in I got the same exact error... I just have no clue how to attack this at this point. Kind enough to hop into a Zoom call

Comment: Please don't add needless links to your website in an answer. The community will treat this as spam. Only link to your content when strictly necessary, and make sure to add disclosure when doing so.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create the `covidbb` file, it is not found, you might have it not in the same directory as the script

Comment: Or the file is `covidbb.csv`?

Comment: Maybe they meant `coviddb` too?

Comment: that is what I did, I took it from another CSV and created the covidbb file. It appears none of my CSVs are on the same directory as script at this point from the instillation possibly

Comment: @RFossati then move those CSVs to the same directory as the script :)

Comment: stupid question - but how do go about that

Comment: @RFossati Where is the script, where are the CSVs and what OS are you on?

Comment: I put the script from Jupyter in the same folder as the CSV currently is in. I am on Windows

Comment: open cmd in your project's directory and type `copy Jupyter\*.csv .`

Comment: It says ' The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: @RFossati is the `Jupyter` folder there?

Answer (score 0):

Copy this test script in the same directory as your current script.

`test.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

df = pd.read_csv(pathlib.Path(__file__) / 'covidbb')
print(df)
```

Comment: Just gave it a shot as you sent it...

Comment: This is my current error: NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Comment: You have not executed the script, you have copy/paste on a python console.